# Firefox SSO/NTLM auth to SharePoint Foundation 2013 Web app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, ntlm, sso, firefox

I am facing isse with my FireFox SSO/NTLM auth to Sharepoint Web App. It works fine for IE and Chrome. I been tryng newest version of FF and oldones version like 47 or 46 and same result. I was configuring once in other client dev env about:config file like few years ago and it worked then. No seems does not work at all. I am giving up with this please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I debugged the https protocol by fiddler and I found that when I was opening my web app authentication at first used Basic-auth then Windows auth.
Windows auth was set up with two Negotiable and NTLM auth methods. I disabled Basic-auth and Removed Negotiable from Windows leaving just NTLM auth method.
It worked!